# Change String to date using LocalDate in Java

Tags: java, localdate

I need to change String date="20160101" to "January 1,2016" by using `LocalDate`.
Right now, my code looks like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE;
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("20120403", formatter);
System.out.println(date);
```

The output is: 2016-01-01

Do I need to use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to do that, or is there an easier way?
Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html

Answer (score 2):

`LocalDate#toString` method prints the date in ISO-8601 format uuuu-MM-dd. That's why your output is coming as `2016-01-01`. If you need the output in "January 1,2016" format instead, you need to again format the date to `MMM d, yyyy` format.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE;
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("20120403", formatter);
String strDate = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy"));
System.out.println(strDate);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help guys!

Comment: I can't have it returned as a String. It needs to be returned as LocalDate. The only reason why i printed it was because I wanted to test it.

Comment: If that is the case, you already have the LocalDate object. The `date` object is actually a LocalDate object. What's wrong with it>

Comment: @Ahab Date objects don't have formats. The format is added when you convert them to strings.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much for The help!

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use a builder. DateTimeFormatter can be created directly from a string [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0):

## Date-time objects have no format

Your comments indicate that you are conflating date-time objects with strings representing their values.

Date-time objects have no format. The objects can generate strings to represent their values, but such strings are distinct and separate. Likewise, a date-time object can be instantiated by parsing a string, but the new date-object will be distinct and separate.

## Localizing

You can generate a string as shown in the [Answer by VHS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42195127/642706) where you specify a certain formatting pattern. But generally a better route is to let java.time localize automatically for you.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; // Or Locale.US, Locale.ITALY, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( l );
String output = myLocalDate.format( f );
```

The [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) class is for special needs. Generally all you need is the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

See this example [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/KW5Amg). But beware of limitation with that IdeOne.com web site’s implementation of Java: Alternate locales are ignored, hard-coded to a single English locale (perhaps Locale.US).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE;
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("20120403", formatter);

String outputStandard = localDate.toString();

DateTimeFormatter fCanadaFrench = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.LONG )
                     .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
String outputCanadaFrench = localDate.format( fCanadaFrench ) ;

DateTimeFormatter fUS = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.LONG )
                     .withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
String outputUS = localDate.format( fUS ) ;
```

> localDate.toString(): 2012-04-03
>
> outputCanadaFrench: 3 avril 2012
>
> outputUS: April 3, 2012